# How can I fix error: pathspec 'git-practice-project/git-practice-project' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: xcode, swift, git, version-control, gitignore

I've created a project to practice using Git with Xcode and GitHub. After a lot of work, I've got the repositories created both locally and remotely. I just tried to make a commit and got this error:

[image]

Here's what I'm trying to commit:

[image]

The last things I did before I got this error were:

- I added a .gitignore file using the GitHub Swift template in order to remove the .xcscheme file from the cache
- from the Terminal, I ran 'git rm --cache'
- I created the test_file and then tried to Commit

But I can see the folder in the finder:

[image]

I looked around SO a lot and found many questions about git commit problem but what I found had mostly to do with diacritics and other issues that aren't the same as mine.

Did the 'git rm --cache' lead to this situation? What can/should I do to safely correct this problem?

Thanks

**Update**: Seems I really got myself into pickle. I've got nested 'git-practice-project' directories several levels deep:

[image]

I've started at the deepest directory, did an ls, and a git status, the backed myself up to the top doing the same thing at each level. It looks like only the two highest directories have uncommitted changes and the project.pbxproj file exists in both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Xcode's SCM features so I am not sure why Xcode is confused here. But it looks like the files under `git-practice-project/git-practice-project` aren't known to git yet. You need to add the directory to git. On the command line from the project's root directory you could try:

`git status`

That should list your files that have been modified, deleted, and that aren't part of the git repo yet.

Add the directory and its contents:

`git add git-practice-project`

Once you have done that, you should be good to go to use the SCM tools in Xcode again.

**Update:** In Xcode, you can select the file that is marked with the `?` and then go to the **Source Control** menu and select **Add Selected Files**.

Comment: That did it, Bringo, so thank you. If you don't mind, take a look at the edit I made to my question. I added a screenshot from the terminal which shows the mess I created. I added git-practice-project at the top level '/Users/Jim/Developer/git-practice-project' and that's what fixed it. I have no idea why the nested levels exist and I also don't know if I can safely get rid of them. Any suggestions you have would be greatly appreciated. It's just a practice project after all so I can't do any real damage.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this with Xcode 10, with newly added files. You first need to add the new files to the repository. Simply select the file in the navigator on the left, right-click, then Source Control in the pop-up, and select "Add Selected Files". After this the commit will work.